# Pycallgraph not generating graphd output in debug mode

Tags: python, graphviz, call-graph, pycallgraph

I'm using Pycallgraph to generate output, but I want to save the intermediate graphd output (instead of generating an image) because I want to make some small modifications to it.

I'm running as:

```
PYTHONPATH=. pycallgraph -d graphviz -- ./ab_ndh_graph.py > out.graphd
```

Which is generating 2x things:

1. pycallgraph.png -- this is the entire call graph (graphd output in
   out.graphd)
2. filter_max_depth.png -- this is the code based call
   graph (correct, but no graphd output)

How can I get the graphd output to be generated for "filter_max_depth" instead?

File contents:

```
config = Config(max_depth=2)
config.trace_filter = GlobbingFilter(exclude=[
    'pycallgraph.*',
])
graphviz = GraphvizOutput(output_file='filter_max_depth.png')

with PyCallGraph(output=graphviz, config=config):
    o = AB_NDH()
    o.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GraphvizOutput` class uses a temporary file to output the `dot` source to, and runs the `dot` command line tool on that file before cleaning it up again.

However, you can *regenerate* the same file contents rather easily by calling the `generate()` method after running `PyCallGraph`:

```
with open('filter_max_depth.graphd', 'w') as dotfile:
    dotfile.write(graphviz.generate())
```

You could also switch on the debug option of your `config` object; in that case the `dot` source is written to the log. Setting `.debug` flag on the `config` object:

```
config.debug = True
```

but then *don't* use `-d` on the command line:

```
PYTHONPATH=. pycallgraph graphviz -- ./ab_ndh_graph.py > out.graphd
```

Essentially, that's the same as adding `print graphviz.generate()` however.